# Filtering data which only fits the trend in SAS Enterprise Guide

Tags: filter, sas, data-analysis, trend

I have a very interesting case in SAS EG which I would like to solve and which might benefit us all to learn from. I have a big dataset in SAS EG which I use to make charts in VA. These charts (most of them) have a specific trend in a time-frame of 1 minute. The beginning of the chart have values around 17-18, within a few seconds, the values drop to approximately 0 - 1. A few seconds later the value rises again to 17-18.  So the trend starts high goes low and ends high. The data-set looks like this (but much much bigger):

```
Time    --    Value
00:000  --   17.109
00:025  --   17.109
00:040  --   17.106
00:061  --   17.034
00:071  --   17.056
00:151  --    0.431
00:173  --    0.432
00:182  --    0.320
00:195  --    0.650
00:234  --   17.109
00:244  --   17.109
00:256  --   17.106
00:278  --   17.034
00:291  --   17.056
```

Sometimes the chart doesn't fit the trend because the dataset sometimes contains to high or to low values at unwanted places. Now I only want to select the data in EG which fits the trend so that I don't get weird charts in SAS VA. The trend I'm looking for actually has 3 sections: Begin - Middle - End. In the Begin the values must be HIGH between 17 and 18. In the Middle the values must be LOW between 0 and 1. In the End the values must again be HIGH between 17 and 18.

If the values are like I mentioned above, I will get a Bathtub curve which is what I want.

I was thinking about selecting the average of the highest values (the 17's) and the average of the lowest values (the 0's) and then maybe filter which are the closest to those values? I think this might not be accurate enough. I have also read something about the SHEWHART Procedure (I don't know what this is or how this works).

I appreciate your help. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Can you explain the out of place values ? Are they super high spikes, or are you getting sporadic low values intermixed with wanted high values, and sporadic high values intermixed with wanted low values ?  You really need to focus on the criteria for dismissing a value and whether or not a run of sporadic values can trigger a false detection of 'place' (high v low)

Comment: Im getting sporadic low values intermixed with wanted high values.

Comment: What type of chart are you doing ? SERIES SCATTER some other ?  Do you ever get intermediate values (2,4,6,8,10,12,14,16) during a transitioning time frame ?  Does a set of readings ever cover more than one 'bathtub'.  In terms of a 'pulsed' signal, your data set sounds like it records one 'beat'.  Is that always the case ?

Comment: Im using a time series plot. I do get intermediate values. A set of readings from begin to end covers 1 bathtub and is approximately 40 seconds. It indeed is a beat.